# Should we have [that] tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

There's 10 questions with [that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/that). It lacks a tag wiki. Is it a useful tag?

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Sometimes it's being used when asking about whether to use "that" or "which", which has its own tag [which-that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/which-that) such as [that vs which vs what](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223990/that-vs-which-vs-what)

Sometimes it's being used when asking whether to use "that" or "who" [What is the mistake in "There are many Danes who speak English"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425483/what-is-the-mistake-in-there-are-many-danes-who-speak-english)

Sometimes it's being used to ask whether "that" can be simply dropped: [Is it required to use "that" here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209718/is-it-required-to-use-that-here)

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

I guess it's useful to have a tag, because you can't google for the word "that".

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Pretty much the same as number 1.

Comment: IME, no one on EL&U makes much of a fuss about tag cleanups. I’ve never had much of a response to my questions asking whether we should burninate a given tag. Which meant no one was inclined to debate me on its removal, but no one felt energized enough to help me do so, either. I’d suggest you just go ahead and remove the tag from questions which have it. If there’s a ton of them, wait til a quiet time on the site (night EU & US time or a weekend) so the inevitable front page clutter doesn’t rub anyone the wrong way.

Comment: @DanBron Exactly. Somebody had to say it. :)